# Install Gephi Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: java

/gephi-0.9.2/bin$ ./gephi

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/home/herdeirodocaos/gephi-0.9.2/platform/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 112: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the sequence of commands you used to achieve that impressive warning.

Comment: Looks like the program needs java 8 and you provided java 9 or higher. Install java 8 and try it again. If it does not work post the error with a question and some sentences telling us what you try to achieve.

Comment: I've installed java 8 and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Installing and setting Java 8 solved this for me

Following https://docs.datastax.com/en/jdk-install/doc/jdk-install/installOpenJdkDeb.html

check java flavours on system

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --list
```

install java 8

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

set as alternative

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```